# Is it possible to access the mesh created by ARKit?

Tags: ios, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I am learning AR using SwiftUI and RealityKit, and I started with a very basic implementation that first shows only the camera stream.
Later virtual objects should be placed using a ModelEntity and an AnchorEntity.

App:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct BasicARApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct MainView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
}
```

The app that I have in mind requires to identify the object closest to the camera.
To find this object in the mesh generated by the ARKit, [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/content_anchors/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene?language=objc) suggest to raycast from a location through the mesh e.g. using

```
if let result = arView.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first { // … }
```

However I think it would be easier If I had access to the mesh directly, and filter out the nodes closest to the camera.

So my question is: How do I get access to the mesh generated by ARKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code update, partly based on Adarsh Sharma´s answer (+1) and Apple's demo project [Visualizing and Interacting with a Reconstructed Scene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/content_anchors/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene).
Essentially, I had to configure the `session` property of the `ARView` to create the mesh.
Then I can set a breakpoint at `let meshGeometry = meshAnchor.geometry`, and handle the mesh anchor.
PS: This code works on an iPhone 14 Pro under iOS 16.6, even if this device doesn't have a Lidar scanner.
**EDIT**: By now I realized that my iPhone 14 Pro **has** a Lidar scanner.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Configure the ARView to generate a mesh
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        arView.renderOptions = [.disablePersonOcclusion, .disableDepthOfField, .disableMotionBlur]
        
        // Manually configure what kind of AR session to run since ARView on its own does not turn on mesh classification.
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(configuration)

        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        var parent: ARViewContainer
        
        init(_ parent: ARViewContainer) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            for anchor in anchors {
                if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
                    let meshGeometry = meshAnchor.geometry
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hlw @AndyJazz please check this one hope  it will help.

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // Setting the ARView's delegate
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        return arView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}

  
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        var parent: ARViewContainer

        init(_ parent: ARViewContainer) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            for anchor in anchors {
                if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
                    
                    let meshGeometry = meshAnchor.geometry
                   
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but in `func session(_ session:, didUpdate anchors:)`, only a single anchor is obtained, and this one is an `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor` that does not have a `geometry` property. Maybe the app is not yet correctly set to create a mesh?

Comment: You are correct. The ARSessionDelegate method session(_:didUpdate:) provides a list of ARAnchors that have been updated.To obtain the ARMeshAnchor objects that represent the mesh of the real-world scene, you need to enable meshing in your AR session. Meshing generates and updates the mesh representation of the environment as the camera moves.

Comment: 1.)Enable meshing using ARView's sceneUnderstandingOptions.
2.)Implement the ARSessionDelegate in a coordinator class for your ARViewContainer.
3.)In the session(_:didUpdate:) method, check if each anchor is an ARMeshAnchor.
4.)If an ARMeshAnchor is found, access its geometry property to work with the mesh data.
One thing u should remember that meshing requires a device with LiDAR or depth-sensing capabilities. If your device does not support meshing, you may not receive ARMeshAnchor objects. Always test the app on a compatible device to see the mesh data in action.